# How do I export the revision history of a gdoc to git?

Tags: git, google-docs, google-sheets, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet in google docs that I'd want to integrate in a git workflow (and push to github). Are there any tools (or even libraries that are gdoc version aware) that do, or help me do, that?

I have some old ruby hacks lying around based on the [google_spreadsheet gem](https://github.com/gimite/google-spreadsheet-ruby) that reads and writes current versions of a csv gdoc, but nothing which extracts revision history.

Comment: See some 2018-19 work-in-progress on this via R at https://github.com/tidyverse/googledrive/issues/219

Answer (score 10, accepted):

gdoc is not set up for exporting revision history [source](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/How-to-Documents/eTDO2gNzBMk%5B1-25-false%5D).

Google drive does have an API to access all the revisions [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-revisions?hl=en).  That provides an easy way to download all the revisions. Then you can create a script to add them one by one to git. There are some problems with the revision history see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-documents-list-api/2Vw9ju54BS0%5B1-25-false%5D).

Comment: This is very useful research; thank you! Authoritative word on it not being designed for more than reverting to prior states suggests I may be better off rethinking the project, though it might be interesting to experiment with the drive API, if it also applies to all GDocs.

Answer (score 34):

I was intrigued by your question, so I hacked together a little project today:

- https://github.com/larsks/gitdriver

Given a document id, it will create a git repository using either the plain text or HTML content of a Google Docs document.  This could easily be extended to work with other file types.  It looks something like this when it works:

```
$ python gitdriver.py -T 1j6Ygv0ow5A8_ywTMwJbuKVrxrSsSH2wJs3a8Q66mvt4
Create repository "Untitled"
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/lars/projects/gitdriver/Untitled/.git/
[master (root-commit) 24d35e7] revision from 2013-01-08T21:57:38.837Z
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 content
[master fd243ee] revision from 2013-01-08T21:57:45.800Z
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
 rewrite content (95%)
[master 5ad1a26] revision from 2013-01-09T01:47:29.593Z
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
 rewrite content (92%)
$ cd Untitled
$ git log --oneline
5ad1a26 revision from 2013-01-09T01:47:29.593Z
fd243ee revision from 2013-01-08T21:57:45.800Z
24d35e7 revision from 2013-01-08T21:57:38.837Z
```

This requires you to set up the necessary application credentials with Google.  And it doesn't do any error checking.  And may eat your goldfish.  This is meant as a demonstration of the API and how you might do something like this; it's *not* intended to be a functional product.

Comment: This seems a cool start – what python version and dependencies do I need to install to run it? I tried running it with python 2.7 after having run pip install `google-api-python-client`, `pyyaml` and `requests` but still got some backtrace: https://gist.github.com/4514298

Comment: There's something very odd about that traceback; it's reporting that your `os` module has no `urandom` function.  How did you install Python 2.7?  For the record, this works fine under both OS X and Linux (w/ Python 2.7 and requests 1.1.0).

Comment: This is fantastic larsks, thanks for writing it up and posting it. I did have some trouble with truncated revisions lists and such that seem to be fixed by the [this fork of your code](https://github.com/deltaidea/gitdrive). That got the job done for me but you might look into joining forces.